# Classes vs. dictionaries as variable containers to get rid of quotation marks?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I’m trying to better understand the concept of python dictionaries and want to use a dictionary as a container of several variables in my code. Most examples I looked for, show strings as dictionary keys, which implies the use of quotation marks for using keys as variables. However, I found out that one does not need to use quotation marks if the key is firstly given a value and after that placed in a dictionary. Then one get rid of the quotation marks. The variable is then actually an immutable value.  In that case, even as one changes the value of the key, the original value remains in the key and can be retrieved by dictionary method -.keys() (and thus be used to restore the first given value). However, I’m wondering if this is a proper way of coding and if it is better to apply a class as a variable container, which looks more simple but is perhaps slower when executed. Both approaches lead to the same result. See my example below.

```
class Container ():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 15
        self.b = 17

# first given values
a = 5
b = 7

# dictionary approach
container = {a:15, b:17}
print('values in container: ', container[a], container[b])
container[a], container[b] = 25, 27
print('keys and values in container: ', container[a], container[b])
for key in container.keys():
    print('firstly given values: ', key)
print('\n')    

# class approach
cont = Container()
print('values in cont: ', cont.a, cont.b)
cont.a, cont.b = 25, 27
print('keys and values in cont: ', cont.a, cont.b)
```

Comment: What is the fundamental problem with using quotation marks…?

Comment: A [dictionary key can be any hashable value](https://alysivji.github.io/quick-hit-hashable-dict-keys.html).   Lots of examples show strings (i.e. items in quotes), but there are many other hashable values such as numbers, tuples, etc. that can be used as keys in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later you may assign other values to a and b, and the code using dictionary will crash. Using a variable as a key is not a good practice. Do it with the class. You may also add the attributes to the constructor of your class.

```
class Container ():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

# creating
cont = Container(15, 17)

# changin
cont.a, cont.b = 25, 27
```

Answer (score 4):

> However, I found out that one does not need to use quotation marks if the key is firstly given a value and after that placed in a dictionary.

This isn’t really what’s happening. Your code isn’t using `'a'` and `'b'` as dictionary keys. It’s using the *values* of the variables `a` and `b` — which happen to be the integers `5` and `7`, respectively.

Subsequent access to the dictionary *also* happens by value: whether you write `container[a]` or `container[5]` doesn’t matter (as long as `a` is in scope and unchanged). But *it is not the same as `container['a']`, and the latter would fail here.

You can also inspect the dictionary itself to see that it doesn’t have a key called `'a'` (or unquoted, `a`):

```
>>> print(dictionary)
{5: 15, 7: 17}
```

Ultimately, if you want to use *names* (rather than *values*) to access data, use a class, not a dictionary. Use a dictionary when the keys are given as values.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand the class approach, because the dict approach in this case does not seem a proper way to code.

When you do :

```
a = 5
b = 7
container = {a:15, b:17}
```

You actually do :

```
container = {5:15, 7:17}
```

But this is "hidden", so there is a risk that later you reassign your variables, or that you just get confused with this kind of dictionary :

```
container = {
    a:15,
    b:17,
    "a": "something"
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Indeed reassigning the variables leeds to an error when the code executed. I see now my misunderstanding. Many thanks.